# Color only erased parts of layer with locked transparent pixels in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I made a layer that has white contents, then clicked "Lock transparent pixels"
I then proceeded to use the eraser to remove some of the white areas which is to be replaces with a different color.

What I didn't realize is that erasing on a layer locked like that replaces the erased parts with a gray color and doesn't actually make it transparent. Now how can I select this gray erased area to replace it with a diff. color?

Answer (score 1):

**You have to disable transparency lock!!**

You enabled transparency lock when you locked it via `Layer - Lock - Transparency`!! so when your layer has transparency lock then your eraser instead of erasing pixels it'll act like brush and will use "Background Color" as fill color so to make your layer erasable just uncheck transparency lock icon!

So If you want to delete pixels you have to remove Transparency lock and instead of it you can use Position Lock which in next to transparency Lock icon!! Cheers!

[image]

Comment: But now that I already messed up, how do I replace the color put in by the erasement?.. Should I just use color focus? By the way thanks for clarifying it uses background color instead, that helps a lot

Comment: Can't just do Ctrl + Z??? :D

Comment: Nope it was like 300 steps. VERY VERY detailed erasure.

Comment: Lol normally you can only erase as long as your history states. But yeah you can go back to it's original form when you opened it.so if you saved and closed than you can't revert it but if you have still it opened without closing then you cannjust select first option in history panel which will revert back to normal